# Need some insight on following python 3 code

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to build this basic code for fun but I ran into some weird error. The following code asks for an answer of a basic printed out equation. When the answer is 10 or greater, it is behaving weirdly. I tried to implement some error handling methods (**the failure is at int(ansr_raw) I guess**). I think a better method will help me out. You don't need to spell out the code for me but pointing me at the right direction will be helpful. The code and output are given below.

code -

```
import random

signs = ['+', '-']
verbals = ['out', 'quit', 'help', 'break']
while True:
    a, b = random.randint(1, 9), random.randint(1, 9)
    ch = random.choice(signs)
    print("{} {} {} = ?".format(a, ch, b))
    ansr_raw = input("Enter the answer: ")

    if ansr_raw in '0123456789':        # trying to handle error
        ansr = int(ansr_raw)
    else:
        for i in verbals:
            if ansr_raw == i:
                choice = input("Wish to Quit? [y/n] ").lower()
                if choice in 'yes':
                    print("Quit Successful.")
                    break
                elif choice in 'no':
                    continue
                else:
                    print("Wrong choice. continuing game.")
                    continue
        print('answer format invalid')
        continue

    if ch == '+':
        if ansr == (a + b):
            print("Right Answer.")
        else:
            print("wrong answer.")
    elif ch == '-':
        if ansr in ((a - b), (b - a)):
            print("Right Answer.")
        else:
            print("wrong answer.")
```

Here is the output (arrow marks added)-

```
9 + 3 = ?
Enter the answer:  12
answer format invalid    <----
2 - 9 = ?
Enter the answer:  5
wrong answer.
1 - 3 = ?
Enter the answer:  2
Right Answer.
8 + 3 = ?
Enter the answer:  11
answer format invalid    <----
1 + 2 = ?
Enter the answer:  3
Right Answer. 
6 + 2 = ?
Enter the answer:
```

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is as in your code. It seems not to print that for me.

Comment: I checked the indentation several times and it still gave me the error which it shouldn't. Though in python indentations are a mess sometimes and can still bug even after being corrected in a few compilers. If it gave you proper results then I guess it is okay. I will try another compiler tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is where you say

```
if ansr_raw in '0123456789':        # trying to handle error
        ansr = int(ansr_raw)
```

For a single digit number like 9, yes there is a 9 in that string, but there is only a few two digits(01,23,34,45,56,67,78,89), to what you're trying to do, check if the string can become an integer; do this.

```
try:
    ansr = int(ansr_raw)
except ValueError:
```

Full Code:

```
import random
import sys
signs = ['+', '-']
verbals = ['out', 'quit', 'help', 'break']

running = True
while running:
    a, b = random.randint(1, 9), random.randint(1, 9)
    ch = random.choice(signs)
    print("{} {} {} = ?".format(a, ch, b))
    ansr_raw = input("Enter the answer: ")
    try:
        ansr = int(ansr_raw)
    except ValueError:
        answerInv = True
        for i in verbals:
            if ansr_raw == i:
                choice = input("Wish to Quit? [y/n] ").lower()
                if choice in 'yes':
                    print("Quit Successful.")
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif choice in 'no':
                    continue
                    answerInv = False
                else:
                    print("Wrong choice. continuing game.")
                    answerInv = False
                    continue
        if answerInv:
            print('answer format invalid')

    if ch == '+':
        if ansr == (a + b):
            print("Right Answer.")
        else:
            print("wrong answer.")
    elif ch == '-':
        if ansr in ((a - b), (b - a)):
            print("Right Answer.")
        else:
            print("wrong answer.")
```

Comment: This one looks promising. I was thinking about try statement but I am still unfamiliar with the error names so I avoided it. I will give this a try tomorrow.

Comment: I like that `try` code for checking `int` clever stuff :)